# Neo4J what is the fastest structure when you have 3 main entities?

Tags: neo4j

Say you have zip codes, services and customers. Given a zip and service, I want to find the corresponding customers as fast as possible.

Options:

1. Customers are connected to zips via a "service" relationship. this seems like the smallest version, search for a particular zip and only one type of relationship (the targeted service)
2. Customers are connected to service areas, which point to different zips and services. Here we search for all service areas that point to the targeted service and the targeted zip.
3. Zips each connect to a service node unique to them, which are then connected to customers. so when you search, you go to the zip you want, go to the service, then anything connected to there is what you want (this feels like i may be overly hand holding for neo4J)

Do these different versions have different performance? I am having trouble understanding the theoretical difference in search formats in Neo4J. 2 is an example where the results are limited on two sides at once, where for 1 and 3, you can travel linearly on the graph as you filter, does that make a difference?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach 1 has several major drawbacks. All data about a "service" (which I assume is a company that provides services) would have to be duplicated in every associated `service` relationship. That wastes storage space in the DB. Also, if you wanted to find all the customers for a specific service (regardless of zip code), you'd have to scan every `service` relationship.

Approach 2 introduces an extra "service area" layer to the data model that seems to provide no advantage and just makes processing your use case more complicated and slower.

Approach 3 (in which I assume every "service" has a unique node) should be the way to go. There is no data duplication, and no scanning is needed to find the desired customers (whether you start from a zip code, or from a service).

Comment: For #3, I was suggesting each zip would have its own unique "service" node for each type of service. I feel like I need that duplication because a customer maybe "teaches swim lessons" in one zip, but does "reading lessons" in another zip. A customer basically is either in business or not in every zip-service combination.

Is that the same as what you are saying, with each zip having its own set of service nodes, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: My assumption was that a "service" is a company that provides a number of services. But it sounds like you are saying that a "customer" is the provider of a number of services?

Comment: In any case, it does seem weird that a service provider would be so picky that they would only provide services to specific zip codes and not others. But if that does happen, you could create a second Service node.

Comment: Yeah a customer can provide multiple services, so right now I have zip => service => customer, with the services duplicated across zips. that's why I was considering the "service area" (SA) concept, where an SA is connected to services and zips, and applies only to one customer. so zip => SA => service, with the customer being attached to SA or a property. The extra data layer removes the need to have duplicate services, but if that slows down my search (zip+service => list of customers), then I don't wanna go down that route

Comment: If it were me, I would replace the term "Customer" with the more intuitive term "Provider". Also, I do not understand why a single "Service" provided by a "Provider" could not be connected by relationships to any set of zip codes. You should consider whether you really have a use case that *requires* duplcation.

Comment: If I connect Providers with Services and Providers with Zips, I am unsure how I can deal a Provider that does Service A in Zip 12345 and Service B in Zip 67890. The Provider would not support Service B in Zip 12345. Right now duplication is the only answer I have, but my Neo4J understanding is still lacking